# How to edit content and layout of webview?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Is there a way for me to edit the contents of the Webview or to crop out some parts of the content, i'm focusing on UI and would like to clean up the content for a project i am working on.

Also lets say I want to display content of the webView individually as well (multiple webviews within an activity) for aesthetic purposes, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

One technique I've used in the past is to request the page with an `HttpURLConnection` rather than the `WebView`.  Then I parse and edit the HTML data and display it in the `WebView` using the `loadData` method.  You could even use something like JSoup to parse the HTML.  However, if you are depending on having the JavaScript run on the page, you may have a problem because using `loadData` will disrupt the same-origin policy.